# Will changing web.config session timeout to enabled in SharePoint Web App affect other application?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

Senario: I have multiple .aspx page coded with Get session timeout, and the .aspx are stored in SPS .../_layouts/15/MyPages/ folder. Below is my changes on web.config

web.config

```
<pages enableSessionState="true" ... >
...
<add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" preCondition="" />
```

.aspx C# code

```
int milliSec = (this.Session.Timeout * 60000);
```

Will this affect other application in SharePoint? If yes, can my .aspx page have it's own web.config to prevent conflict?

Answer (score 0):

Changes of web.config will affect only corresponding web application. But increasing timeout is generally not a good idea especially when you want to affect only one your page. Much better solution is using [SPLongOperation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splongoperation.aspx) object to implement your logic. There are at least three reasons:

1. It is systematic solution that solves not only timeout but also waiting animation and standard behavior.
2. Setting timeout in web.config affects whole web application not only your page.
3. Any value you put in web.config could be too low for slow systems and too high for fast systems.